# Instruments: checking for memory leaks inquiry

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

I was curious, when one goes ahead and executes their code for leaks checking with Instruments -- is it prudent to hit all of the parts of the app manually to ensure memory leaks are occurring in that respective area? For instance, I believe I have some memory leaks in my application, deep within a UINavigationController tree. Do I go ahead and run the app checking for leaks, while manually drilling down on the iPhone to get to that part of the app? Is Instruments smart enough to find it on its own? What's the proper way of going about it?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Instruments just monitors the memory allocations of your code, it does not "go" anywhere, unless your app goes there. Actually a leak is nothing more than a piece of memory to that no reference exists anymore; thus it cannot be freed anymore, since how are you going to free it in the future if you cannot even reference to it any longer?

Instruments won't find all memory leaks that way, though. If you keep references to the memory, just never use them to free the memory, Instruments won't see this as a leak, because it cannot foresee if you are going to ever free it up in the future or not. As you still could free it up, it's not considered a leak. So if you have a memory issue, it might be beneficial to not just look for leaks, but also to monitor how much memory your application is "collecting" over the time. If this permanently rises even though it shouldn't, you might still have a leak, just none where you lose the references to the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I would focus on the module suspected of causing the leaks and then widen the scope afterward.  While I have not used Instruments on a Mac, I have used Purify and the native Windows heap tools to do memory leak tracing in Windows programs.

After you have identified the source of your major leak it's never a bad idea to run the program with varying test input and generally check the program for other leaks.  Even small leaks with a particular set of data can lead to much larger leaks down the road.